# Logic behind program faulty, program doesn't produce correct output

Tags: python, error-handling, logic

This is a python code to find the token type ratio (all definitions given below in the code). I cannot get the correct value. I suspect that my logic is faulty and i am not capable o debugging my logic. I would appreciate any help

```
def type_token_ratio(text):
    """ 
    (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and
    text contains at least one word.

    Return the Type Token Ratio (TTR) for this text. TTR is the number of
    different words divided by the total number of words.

    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
        'James Gosling\n']
    >>> type_token_ratio(text)
    0.8888888888888888
    """

    x = 0
    while x < len(text):
        text[x] = text[x].replace('\n', '')
        x = x + 1
    index = 0
    counter = 0
    number_of_words = 0

    words = ' '.join(text)
    words = clean_up(words)
    words = words.replace(',', '')
    lst_of_words = words.split()

    for word1 in lst_of_words:
        while index < len(lst_of_words):
            if word1 == lst_of_words[index]:
                counter = counter + 1
            index = index + 1
    return ((len(lst_of_words) - counter)/len(lst_of_words))
```

Comment: It's not clear what do u want to do ? what is the desired output ? what does "clean_up" does ?

Comment: i don't catch you logic either...for the first word in lst_of_words you consume whole index range in your while and don't reset it, so for next word index == len(lst_of_word). so while is played only for the first word. secondly a word is always at least equals to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you might have wanted to write ( replacing your code starting from -for- ).

```
 init_index=1
 for word1 in lst_of_words:
    index=init_index
    while index < len(lst_of_words):
        if word1 == lst_of_words[index]:
            counter=counter+1
            break
        index = index + 1
    init_index = init_index + 1
    print word1
 print counter
 r=(float(len(lst_of_words) - counter))/len(lst_of_words) 
 print '%.2f' % r
 return r
```

=> index=init_index is in fact index of word following word1; while search always restarts at next word.

=> break : to not count multiple times same occurence, one occurence by for iteration.

you are searching if there is a word that is duplicate of this in the remaining of the list ( since up to this word was already done by previous iterations )

care should be done to not recount many time smae occurence, that's why there is a break. if there are mutliple occurence of the same word, next occurence will be found at a further iteration.

not bullet proof, based on your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a far simpler way of doing this - using the collections modules :

```
import collections 

def type_token_ratio(text): 
   """ (list of str) -> float

   Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and
   text contains at m one word.

   Return the Type Token Ratio (TTR) for this text. TTR is the number of
   different words divided by the total number of words.

   >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
       'James Gosling\n']
   >>> type_token_ratio(text)
   0.8888888888888888
   """
   words = " ".join(text).split() # Give a list of all the words
   counts = collections.Counter(words)
   all = sum([counts[i] for i in counts])
   unique = len(counts)
   return float(unique)/all
```

or as @Yoel pointed out- there is an even simpler way :

```
  def type_token_ratio(text): 
       words = " ".join(text).split() # Give a list of all the words
       return len(set(words))/float(len(words))
```

Comment: I think you can simply return `float(len(set(words)))/len(words)`.

Comment: Yoel - you are right - I have been using the collections module so much lately i forgot the even simpler method.

Comment: Tony- Thank you so much but the problem is that i am a college freshman and i have just started to learn python and my prof is well aware of that. So if i show this to him he will surely suspect of something. Is there a chance that you can dumb this solution down to my level. Thanks

Comment: @TanayÖnder - ise the simpler of the two version - join, split are part of the standard library that are critical to any and all programs - and all your code does is tries to do some of what they do, (bizzarely by using them :-)). set is a standard data structure, nothing special. I understand your issues but really your code is much too complex, and I am sure your prof would not want that.

Comment: @TanayÖnder - for instance read up on `split` - you seem to assume that it splits only on spaces, whereas if you don't pass an argument it will split using anything that can't be a word (for instance newlines, space, punctuations etc) - try it yourself.